# Unable to encode properly

Tags: python, csv

When launching under Python 3.5.1, the following code produces the error:

File "D:/Python/Kut/exceltocsv.py", line 22, in sheets_tocsv
writobj.writerow([entry for entry in rowvalues])

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Could anyone help me fixing it? ( I was deliberately using openpyxl instead of xlrd. )

```
import os
import openpyxl
import csv

def sheets_tocsv(file, place):     
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    sheetnames = workbook.get_sheet_names()


    for sheetname in sheetnames:
        worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)

        csv_file = open(''.join([place, sheetname, '.csv']), 'wb')   
        writobj = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)  


        for row in range(worksheet.get_highest_row()):   
            rowvalues = []
            for i in worksheet.rows[row]:
                rowvalues.append(str(i.value))
            writobj.writerow([entry.encode() for entry in rowvalues])  
        csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Dropping the .encode() may work.

Comment: I dropped the .encode(), but it still doesn't want to work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with csv, so I don't know. maybe do `bytes(entry.encode(), "ENCODING")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is underdocumented, but Python 3's `csv` is expecting your file to be opened in text rather than bytes mode.

(Also, from the docs, you should set `newline=''` in your `open` call).

Try `open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')`